# Why wont a variable I set in my If statement work outside that if statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have this if statement shown below and i cant use the variable letter outside the if statement in the section below it. any ideas whats wrong?

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 65) {
            context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
            letter = "a";
            context.font = '50pt Calibri';
            context.textAlign = 'center';
            context.fillStyle = 'white';
            context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
            alert(letter + " was pressed");
});

 document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {                     
            if(event.keyCode == 13) {                                              
                alert(letter + " and enter was pressed");
            }
        });
```

edited:

This is my full code and it is still not working. Any more ideas?

```css
/* Hangman Game CSS File */
body
{
 background-color: #9b59b6;
}

#main {
 background-color: #3498db;
 height: 97vh; 
    width: 95vw;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
canvas {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Hangman by Lachlan Teale</title> 
  <meta name="description" content="Lachlan Teale's Hangman Game 2015">
  <meta name="keywords" content="hangman, lachlan, teale, Javascript">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Lachlan Teale">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <canvas id="main" width="1920" height="1080" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 //setting variables
  var canvas = document.getElementById('main');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
       var underscore = "";
       var letter;
       var complete = false;

 //list of words
  var wordList = ["apple", "peach", "pear", "mango", "banana", "paper", "pens", "laptop", "desk", "chair", "star", "sky", "moon", "sun", "planets"];

 //picking a random word from the list
  var word = wordList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length)];

 //print out the underscores for the number of letters
  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
   var underscore = underscore + "_ ";
  }

  context.font = '50pt Calibri';
       context.textAlign = 'center';
       context.fillStyle = 'white';
       context.fillText(underscore, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.70);

    //correct letter text
       context.font = 'bold 30pt Calibri';
       context.textAlign = 'center';
       context.fillStyle = 'white';
       context.text
       context.fillText("Correct Letters", canvas.width * 0.08, canvas.height * 0.05);

    //Wrong Letter text
       context.font = 'bold 30pt Calibri';
       context.textAlign = 'center';
       context.fillStyle = 'white';
       context.text
       context.fillText("Wrong Letters", canvas.width - (canvas.width * 0.08), canvas.height * 0.05);


//while (complete = false) {

 //checking which button is pressed
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
      if(event.keyCode == 65) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
          letter = "a";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
         alert(letter + " was pressed");

      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 66) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
          var letter = "b";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 67) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "c";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 68) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "d";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 69) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "e";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 70) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "f";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 71) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "g";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 72) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "h";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 73) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "i";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 74) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "j";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 75) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "k";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 76) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "l";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 77) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "m";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 78) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "n";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 79) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "o";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 80) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "p";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 81) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "q";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 82) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "r";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 83) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "s";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 84) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "t";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 85) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "u";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 86) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "v";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 87) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "w";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 88) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "x";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 89) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "y";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
   }
      else if(event.keyCode == 90) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var letter = "z";
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = 'white';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
         }
         else if(event.keyCode == 8) {
          context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);
         }
  });


       document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {                     // Wont print out the Letter Variable set in the statements
      if(event.keyCode == 13) {              // Set in the if  statements above.
       alert(letter + " and enter was pressed");
      }
     });
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Holy redundancy, Batman! You don't actually have to write the same code for every letter of the alphabet. You could do `letter = String.fromCharCode( event.keyCode ).toLowerCase();` and have just *one* code block.

Comment: And yes, the problem is that you use `var letter = ...` to set the variable, which turns it into a local variable. Drop the `var` and it should work.

Comment: @Juhana I'm only a high school student learning this for a term, you just saved me a lot of work and thank you greatly for it.

Comment: @Juhana would you be able to show me quickly how to use that code you suggested?

Comment: Just replace `if( event.keyCode == 65 )` with `if( event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90 )` and `letter = "a"` with the code in the previous comment and you can delete every else if... block.

Comment: @Juhana Life saver. You're truly amazing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I've run your code, and if you press 'a' and enter, it works, but if you just press 'enter', you will get an error 'letter is not defined'.

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4ocd0p8/)

Here's why:

If you write this code in javascript:

```
letter = 'a';
```

and there is no variable `letter` in scope, it will create a new variable `window.letter`.

Your document event listener will now be able to reference `window.letter`.

If you hadn't pressed `a`, the document event listener will run this code

```
    alert(letter + " and enter was pressed");
```

and try to read a variable called `letter`, and throw an error `letter is not defined`.

What you NEED to do is create a global `letter` variable yourself. Before defining either listener, simply add the line

```
var letter;
```

This will create a variable in the scope of your code block, and assign it the value `undefined`.

Now, if you press return before pressing 'a', you'll get

```
undefined and enter was pressed
```

Probably not exactly what you want, but at least you can understand what's going on :-)

**Later Edit (After being provided with the whole code)**

See this code:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 65) {
            letter = 'a';
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == 66) {
            var letter = 'b';
        } 
        else if (event.keyCode == 67) {
            var letter = 'c';
        }
```

There is now at least one instance in your event handling function where you declare the `letter` variable preceeded by the keyword `var`. 
This creates a variable `letter` that is only visible within that function. There may be a `letter` variable outside this function, but, within the function, that is going to be ignored in favor of your function-scoped variable.

You must remove the `var` keyword that preceeds the `letter` variable name wherever it appears in the function block. Then it will find and use the `letter` variable that's declared outside the function block.

Comment: I've edited my code to include a snippet showing all my code. It appears your solution didn't work but you seem to know your way around this if you could have a look.

Comment: @MrTeale - OK, I've edited my answer in the light of your additional code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that `letter` is in a different `if` statement; it's in a completely different function.

Learn about variable scoping and this will all make sense.

Comment: `letter` is a global variable.

Comment: It's not my code, but because the variable isn't declared with `var` inside the function then it's implicitly global.

Comment: Can I not set my variable in a function and then use it elsewhere in my code?

Comment: Ok, the variable *was* declared with `var` in the actual code but not in the original question. (That's relevant information, @MrTeale.)